# Showing custom taxonomy column in taxonomy category listings immediately after create category

Tags: taxonomy

I add my custom taxonomy column with this code:

```
function manage_my_category_columns($columns)
    {
     if ( !isset($_GET['taxonomy']) || $_GET['taxonomy'] != 'products' )
     return $columns;
     $columns['image_column'] = 'Image';
     return $columns;
}
add_filter('manage_edit-products_columns','manage_my_category_columns');

function manage_category_custom_fields($deprecated,$column_name,$term_id){
     if ($column_name == 'image_column') {
       $t_id = $term_id;
       $cat_meta = get_option( "products_$t_id");
       echo "<img src='".$cat_meta['img']."' style='height:50px;width:50px;'/>";

     }
    }
add_action('manage_products_custom_column','manage_category_custom_fields',10,3);
```

When I add new category, custom column not shown immediately after create:
[image]

After page refresh the custom column will be shown:
[image]

Is there any way to show custom column with default columns immediately after create new category?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is happening is that:

- the page `/wp-admin/edit-tags.php` uses `$_GET['taxonomy']`
- and `/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`, fired when we create a new term, uses `$_POST['taxonomy']`

To solve it, use `$_REQUEST` in `manage_my_category_columns()`.
It will cover both GET and POST:

```
if ( !isset( $_REQUEST['taxonomy']) || $_REQUEST['taxonomy'] != 'products' )
```

---

**Related Q&A:**
*[WP List Table custom quick edit box - post meta data missing and columns change on submit](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/31154/12615)*